# Splitting tables (stacked cells to horizontal placement)

Tags: tables

I have defined a table like this

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Text~\ref{dom-real}
    \begin{table} [!t]
    \centering  
    \caption{cap}
    \label{dom-real}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm} p{1cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{T1}}  \\ 
            A  &   32\% \\
            B  &   19\% \\
            C  &   15\% \\
            D  &   7\% \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{T2}}  \\ 
            E  &   77\% \\
            F  &   19\% \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
\endinput
```

and the output is shown below

[image]

Now I want to move the bottom section (T2) to the right of the top section (T1). I know the rows are not the same. So, I want to see something like this:

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far in order to achieve the layout you want to have? Just use 4 columns and add the contents related to the second half of the table into colum 3and 4. For a shorter horizontal line, use cline instead of hline and in order to get rid of the vertical line at the bottom right, use multicolumn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply write two `tabular`s besides each other.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{4cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{T1}} \\ 
A  &   32\% \\
B  &   19\% \\
C  &   15\% \\
D  &   7\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{4cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{T2}} \\ 
E  &   77\% \\
F  &   19\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the second `\multicolumn`, I think it would be better to put `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{T2}}` for the case the user loads `array`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Absolutely true, I missed that, thx.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that having no space between the two in the code is essential

Answer (score 2):

With a single `tabular` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Text~\ref{dom-real}
    \begin{table} [!t]
    \centering  
    \caption{cap}
    \label{dom-real}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{4cm} p{1cm}|}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{T1}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{T2}}\\ 
            A  &   32\%                    & E  &   77\% \\
            B  &   19\%                    & F  &   19\% \\ \cline{3-4}
            C  &   15\%\\
            D  &   7\% \\
        \cline{1-2}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
\endinput
```